# why does my Sonarcloud multicriteria configuration not working

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, stenciljs, sonarlint

I am trying to ignore few code smells that are irrelevant to my project using the below config in the .sonarcloud.properties file. But still sonarcloud shows them in the analysis. What am I doing wrong? BTW we have our code in stencil and the rule I am trying to ignore is for className in jsx and key in jsx

```
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria=e1,e2
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.ruleKey=typescript:S6477
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e1.resourceKey=**/*
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.ruleKey=typescript:S6747
sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria.e2.resourceKey=**/*
```